# GoogleFinance Beta on a specific date?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-finance

How can I get the Beta for a stock on a specific date?
I can get the current day's beta using the following

```
=GoogleFinance("BB","beta")
```

however, this formula does not work on specific dates

```
=GoogleFinance(B2,"beta", "2020/12/17")
```

Note: I'm open to using means other than GoogleFinance (Ex. Excel, websites, 3rd party extensions....) to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

beta is not supported directly in google sheets for a historical date.

you need `daily` or `weekly` closed values for `3` or `5` years based on what beta variant you want to calculate

```
=GOOGLEFINANCE("BB", "close", 2020-5&"/12/17", "2020/12/17", "weekly")
```

and then input it into this equation:

```
β = cov(BB, SP500)/var(SP500)
```

googlefinance does not support `monthly` so for that you need to use:

```
=QUERY(SORTN(SORT({
      GOOGLEFINANCE("BB", "close", 2020-3&"/12/17", "2020/12/17", "weekly"), 
 TEXT(GOOGLEFINANCE("BB", "close", 2020-3&"/12/17", "2020/12/17", "weekly"), 
 "mm/yyyy")}, 1, 0), 9^9, 2, 3, 0), 
 "select Col1,Col2 order by Col1 asc", 1)
```